# Send and receive generic list from wcf service using android

Tags: java, c#, android, wcf

I'm new to android, Looking for a generic solution to send and receive c# generic list from a wcf service in android application.I will have copy of Equipment class in android also want to convert the list returned from GeEquipments to generic array list in android and also send list to set equipment, Since I have many more objects I'm looking for generic solution which can be used by any objects.

```
[DataContract]
public class Equipment 
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{  
    [OperationContract]
    List<Equipment> GetEquipments();

    [OperationContract]
    bool  SetEquipments( List<Equipment> equipments);
}

public class RService : IService
{
    public List<Equipment> GetEquipments()
    {
       var equipments = new List<Equipment>();

       equipments.Add(new Equipment()
       {
           Name = "Equipment 1",
           SerialNo = "E001",
           Description = "New Equipment",
           Active = true
       });

       equipments.Add(new Equipment()
       {
           Name = "Equipment 2",
           SerialNo = "E002",
           Description = "New Equipment",
           Active = true
       });

       return equipments;
    }

    public bool SetEquipments(List<Equipment> equipments)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain breifly? what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to get and set generic list from wcf service in android, You will get array of item, Then it should be converted to android class, Same class will be there in wcf service and android code